# why multiple passes for building Linux From Scratch (LFS)?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to understand the concept of Linux From Scratch and would like to know why there are multiple passes for building `binutils`, `gcc` etc.

Why do we need pass1 and pass2 separately? Why can't we build the tools in pass 1 and then use them to build `gcc` , `glibc`, `libstdc++` , etc.

Comment: Not just Linux From Scratch, btw -- this is how it works pretty much everywhere, even if it's being done by your OS vendor on their own official build systems. No responsible distro vendor will build a distro's packages on any platform that doesn't match than that distro itself, because doing so means your binaries may not be reproducible by customers running what you generate.

Comment: This is a classic chicken-and-egg situation. Maybe it can also be called catch-22. Anywhere you need to build a tool that needs that tool to build it, you have to bootstrap it. In your case, you want to build Linux using Linux that you don't have.

Comment: @hek2mgl no it is not! The text on LFS says `Slightly adjusting the name of the working platform, by changing the "vendor" field target triplet by 
way of the LFS_TGT variable, ensures that the first build of Binutils and GCC produces a 
compatible cross-linker and cross-compiler. Instead of producing binaries for another architecture, 
the cross-linker and cross-compiler will produce binaries compatible with the current hardware.` 

This does not explain the `two passes` of gcc or binutils

Comment: I reverted my down-vote. I don't want to be a fool and actually I like when someone plays around with LFS. That's cool! But the LFS book explains that very well: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/toolchaintechnotes.html

Comment: thanks everyone. Things are more clear now.

Comment: Related for newlib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457835/why-do-cross-compilers-have-a-two-stage-compilation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The goal is to ensure that your build is consistent, no matter which compiler you're using to compile your compiler (and thus which bugs that compiler has).

Let's say you're building gcc 4.1 with gcc 3.2 (I'm going to call that gcc 3.2 "stage-0"). The folks who did QA for gcc 4.1 didn't test it to work correctly when built with any compiler other than gcc 4.1 -- hence, the need to first build a stage-1 gcc, *and then use that stage-1 to compile a stage-2 compiler*, to prevent any bugs in the stage-0 compiler from impacting the final result.

Then, the default compile process for gcc uses the stage-2 compiler to build a stage-3 compiler, *and compares the two binaries*: Any difference between them can be used as proof of presence of a bug.

(Of course, this is only an effective mechanism to avoid *unintended* bugs; see the classic Ken Thompson paper [Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) for a discussion of how *intended* bugs can survive this kind of measure).

---

This goes beyond gcc into the entire toolchain because the same principles apply throughout: If you have any differences in the result between building glibc-x.y on a system running glibc-x.y and a system running glibc-x.(y-1) and you *don't* do an extra pass to ensure that you're building in a match for your target environment, then reproducing those bugs (and testing proposed fixes) is made far more difficult than would otherwise be the case: Nobody who doesn't have your (typically undisclosed) build environment can necessarily recreate the bug!

Comment: Well said. It used to be called bootstrapping. I used to bootstrap gcc on Sparc/Solaris.

Comment: If that is the case, then considering the steps in LFS document and your answer, I should build `gcc` twice. First, using the host system compiler and then using the built cross-compiler, right ? Why are there three builds of `gcc` : `Pass 1` , `Pass 2` and then inside the `chroot` ?

Comment: @Monku, for gcc specifically, the double-pass approach is internal to the build system. Thus, building your bootstrap toolchain involves two passes; and building your target likewise involves two passes.

Comment: @Monku, ...now, the LFS folks *could* use `--disable-bootstrap` at configure time for the target instance (not the bootstrap one), if they're building the target gcc with the same version they used for the bootstrap gcc, but speaking as someone who's been half the (non-toolchain) userland team for a commercial Linux distro before, optimizing for performance over correctness is the Wrong Thing.

Answer (score 3):

I know this query is a bit old, but I have something to add to the answers: a clarification of the meaning of 'bootstrap'.

The primary reason for the multi-stage build is to eliminate *every* vestige of the build host's programs/config/libs from the resultant software. It's not enough to have fresh software compiled. You also have to avoid any and all references to the host's libraries, the host's kernel interfaces (kernel headers), the host's pkg versions, and all other such dependencies on the host system.

Suppose you happened to be a masochist and wanted to build Debian 4 on Fedora 27 (it *should* be possible). Simply building the software would pull in references to 27's libraries and other things. And your resultant system would not run because those things are not available when the final system is installed.

LFS eases the process somewhat by building simple x86-to-x86 binutils and gcc cross tools in Stage 1, then installing the headers for the kernel to be used in the final system, then glibc. Stage 2 (binutils and gcc) is built using the cross tools, which guarantees that the host's programs/libs/config are not used at all. The rest of the toolchain (I call it Stage 3) is built using the tools from Stage 2. Now the final stage can be built (with a few small adjustments) with the assurance that no part of the build host will be referenced or used, and that no part of the toolchain will be referenced or used. The final stage is built using a path much like PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/tools/bin; thus as the final tools are built, they will be used instead of those in the toolchain.

Building a toolchain is not for the impatient. It took me months to update Smoothwall Express' build system and the pkgs used, because building a toolchain is fraught with peril. I battled many dragons, balrocs, and dwarfs. I referenced LFS often to figure out how they did it. The result is an automated *re-entrant* build system that builds the entire distro with no references to the host system. I primarily build it on Debian 8, but it's been known to build on Gentoo, and it supposed to be able to build on itself.